# Pattern Matching in robot framework : python

Tags: python, string, cookies, robotframework

Have a code which will compare the pattern of cookie produced when hitting a url using robot framework ,
with a string variable .

```
REGMATCH
     ${string}=  set variable   hgf
     ${matches}=  get regexp matches  ${string}  asdfhgfpoyrjgrrhkjhoolk
     should be equal as strings  ${matches}  hgf
```

but this returns False ,

and i tried this below ,

```
Get Lines Matching Pattern Matching Some Lines
    Test Get Lines Matching Pattern    asdfhgfpoyrjgrrhkjhoolk    ??????   hgf
 
 ***KEYWORD***
Test Get Lines Matching Pattern
    [Arguments]    ${input}    ${pattern}    ${expected}    ${case-insensitive}=no
    ${actual} =    Get Lines Matching Pattern    ${input}    ${pattern}    ${case-insensitive}
    Should Be Equal    ${actual}    ${expected}
```

Can anyone help me in this please .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
${actual} =    Get Lines Matching Pattern    ${input}    ${pattern}    ${case-insensitive}
```

your pattern is `?????` which means exactly 5 characters the input has more than 5 characters

asdfhgfpoyrjgrrhkjhoolk    can be retrieved using that much '?' as ? reprecents one character in glob format, you can use

```
${actual} =    Get Lines Matching Pattern    ${input}    *    ${case-insensitive}
```

which means entire string

For your y=use case you can use

```
Should Match Regexp    hithsihdisdh hsdaasidh 123 dfsdfdsf   123
```

this will check if the string has "123" . This keyword is from Builin library

```
Library    BuiltIn
```

**Below example shows correct usage of each of the keywords:**

```
*** Setting ***
Library    String
Library    BuiltIn
Library  Selenium2Library


*** Test Cases ***
Example Search
    [Tags]    you    probably    do    not    have    this    many    tags    in    real    life
    ${first} =  Catenate    SEPARATOR=\n    Not in second   Same stuff  Differs Same
    #this is use ful to find line the pattern       
    ${a}=    Get Lines Matching Pattern     ${first}   Same*    case_insensitive=true

    #this match the entire multi line string has any match
    ${b}=    Should Match Regexp    ${first}   Same

    #this gives a list of all matches
    ${c}=    Get Regexp Matches    ${first}   Same

    Log    ${a}
    Log    ${b}
    Log    ${c}
```